# Composer: A non-empty PSR-4 prefix must end with a namespace separator

Tags: php, composer-php

I am still experiencing this error, even though my composer.json looks fine.

This is my composer file

```
{
"name": "emmajiugo/chuck-norris-jokes",
"description": "Create random Chuck Norris Jokes",
"type": "library",
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "emmajiugo",
        "email": "emmajiugo@gmail.com"
    }
],
"require": {},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Emmajiugo\\ChuckNorrisJokes\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Emmajiugo\\ChuckNorrisJokes\\Test": "tests"
    }
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
}
}
```

I tried running composer selfupdate but still experience the error.

someone please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the backslash after Test. Your composer.json file should look like this:

```
{
    "name": "emmajiugo/chuck-norris-jokes",
    "description": "Create random Chuck Norris Jokes",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "emmajiugo",
            "email": "emmajiugo@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Emmajiugo\\ChuckNorrisJokes\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Emmajiugo\\ChuckNorrisJokes\\Test\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
    }
}
```